# How to stream music from notebook to speakers via wi-fi?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, audio, speakers, audio-streaming

I have a Windows 7 notebook and speakers in some rooms of my house. I'd like to stream music from notebook to speakers over wi-fi or bluetooth. I don't want to use wires between notebook and speakers.

Is there a device which is able to receive a audio stream from my notebook and play it via speakers or how else can I stream music?

Comment: We're going to need more information about your speakers and how they are set up.  No doubt they are hooked up to some kind of audio receiver/amplifier/AV equipment.

Comment: I use standard PC speakers, Logitech z4i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is through the [Apple Airport Express](http://www.apple.com/airportexpress/features/airplay.html). You just plug it into an outlet and plug your speakers into it. Then the speakers show up in iTunes available for playback. It should work fine with Windows or OSX.

Comment: It's also worth noting Rogue Amoeba's [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) product line, for when you don't want to use iTunes, or when you want to stream the music to other Macs/PCs as well. Apple TV can receive the stream as well. And using AirPort Expresses and Apple TVs means you can stream to them super easily from iPad, iPod touch, and iPhone too.

Comment: It seems like this is what I was looking for, however I need to check it